# Combine two different time format.

Tags: sas

I have this SAS code as bottom in select part:

```
,datepart(pertito_time_entry_date) format=weekdate.  as b
, (input(substr(pertito_time_in,1,2) || ":" ||substr(pertito_time_in,3,4), time.)) format=time. as c
, (input(substr(pertito_time_out,1,2) || ":" ||substr(pertito_time_out,3,4), time.)) format=time.  as d
```

I need to combine (b and c) and (b and d) Then I will need

```
sum(24* (bc - bd) )
```

Let me give an example:

```
 b=Wednesday,Jul10,2011
c=11:00:00
d=10:00:00
```

I need to do

```
 sum( 24*(Jul102011:11:00:00  -  Jul102011:10:00:00 ))
```

How can I combine and make sum? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `b`.  `c-d` will always be sufficient, because the date can't affect things if it's the same for both times.  If you had `a` (another date) for `c`, then you would use

```
dhms(a,0,0,c) - dhms(b,0,0,d)
```

Which also would work here, but would be extraneous.

Further, your `24*` may be wrong; is that 24 as in hours?  Time is always stored in seconds in SAS, so it would be `86400*` if you want to get back to days from seconds.

If your end goal is a datetime with the date `b` and the difference between c and d, then

```
dhms(b,0,0,(c-d))
```

will give you that (though I'm not sure I would suggest that is a useful field).

Comment: Joe, when I use dhms(b,0,0,(c-d)), gives me huge numbers. but I need Jul102011:11:00:00  -  Jul102011:10:00:00 . So it could be 60 or 1. It gives me 10 digit numbers?

Comment: If you want `c-d` then just do that and don't bother with the date/time bit.